# Selenium redirects me back to the starting page when i do driver.get(url)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am scrapping this webpage:http://www.cpcb.gov.in/CAAQM/frmReportdisplay.aspx
after clicking on submit button ,the content of the page changes while url remains same . I want to access those contents but not able to do when i do print(driver.current_url) i see the content of starting page.
How do i access those contents?

**After submitting:**
Page content is this one.

[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time 
chromedriver_loc = '/home/ninjakx/Desktop/mywork/chromedriver-Linux64' 
# enter path of chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_loc)
url ="http://www.cpcb.gov.in/CAAQM/frmUserAvgReportCriteria.aspx"
driver.get(url)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ddlState'))
# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('Delhi')
time.sleep(10)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ddlCity'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Delhi')
time.sleep(5)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ddlStation'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Dwarka')
time.sleep(10)

your_choice.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnAdd"]').click()
time.sleep(13)
your_choice=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='lstBoxChannelLeft']/option[@value='874']")
your_choice.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnAdd"]').click()
time.sleep(13)
your_choice=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='lstBoxChannelLeft']/option[@value='1366']")
your_choice.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnAdd"]').click()
time.sleep(13)
your_choice=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='lstBoxChannelLeft']/option[@value='1377']")

your_choice.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnAdd"]').click()
time.sleep(13)
your_choice=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='lstBoxChannelLeft']/option[@value='864']")
your_choice.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnAdd"]').click()
time.sleep(13)
your_choice=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='lstBoxChannelLeft']/option[@value='824']")
your_choice.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnAdd"]').click()
time.sleep(13)
your_choice=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='lstBoxChannelLeft']/option[@value='502']")
your_choice.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnAdd"]').click()
time.sleep(13)

datefield = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtDateFrom"]')
datefield.click()
datefield.clear()
datefield.send_keys("01/01/2017")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnSubmit"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
cur_url = driver.current_url
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: Is it Iframe inside which content is being changed ..clicking on submit button?

Comment: Yeah only content are changing .

Comment: ...I can see page url is changing...the url you requested is different from one which is after clicking submit button...compare the url in script and url in screenshot

Comment: Well i resolved it 4 days ago so now i am not having any problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have to again visit the link.Just have to continue writing script to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

is this not just a typing error?

you typed:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnSubmit"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
cur_url = driver.current_url
driver.get(url)
```

I think it should be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnSubmit"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
cur_url = driver.current_url
driver.get(cur_url) #changed here
```

Comment: There is no change in url after submitting it

Comment: When i do print(driver.get(current_url)) i see the starting page content not those ones .